# Making phpStorm default editor of php or other supported files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ide

How do I can make phpStorm default editor of php or other supported files in Ubuntu? Php storms is run using a `.sh` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/2-ways-to-change-default-text-editor-in-ubuntu/).

It will set default editor. you can select phpstorm to set as default editor for all files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answer. But PHPstorm have a special structure. It is a java program that runs from a .sh file.